# SQL Server: Count the number of times the ID from table A occurs in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have two tables: products and orders. Orders references products via ProductID as a foreign key. I want to know how many times each product has been sold, including the product being sold only once. I can almost get it to work using a left join, but that still gives one row with a count of one for all products, regardless of whether they exist in the orders table or not.

Is there a way to do this that will have you ending up with something like this?

```
Product | Times sold
Milk    | 5
Bread   | 18
Cheese  | 0
```

... and so on.

Comment: If you don't want products with no orders returned, then change your `LEFT JOIN` to be an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: a `LEFT JOIN` is the right thing to do, specially if in your example you want to list "cheese", wich has been sold zero times

Comment: If you don't want rows that have no orders, then why does your example output show "Cheese  | 0"?

Comment: @ean5533 - The Op wants it to say `0`, not `1`.  Which is the difference between `COUNT(id)` and `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you just do a `COUNT(*)`, then you're counting products that have no orders as 1... instead, `COUNT(o.OrderID)`, which will only count the records that have a non-null `OrderID`.

```
SELECT p.Product, COUNT(o.OrderID)
FROM
    Products p LEFT JOIN
    Orders o ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Product
```

Comment: I think that this is what the op is currently doing

Comment: My guess is that he's doing a `left join`, so that it shows `products` that have no `orders`, but he's doing a `count(*)`, so it shows them with a count of 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Ah! I'd been staring myself blind on the query, not realizing I was using COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(ProductID)

Answer (score 1):

@Michael is correct.

If you have an order table with a count it would look like this:

```
SELECT p.Product, SUM(ISNULL(o.ItemCount,0)) as [Count]
FROM
    Products p LEFT JOIN
    Orders o ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select Products.ProductName, Count(Orders.OrderID)
From Orders Inner join on Products Where Orders.ProductID = Products.ProductID
Group By Products.ProductName
```